# Hibernate cascading multiple layers

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's assume we have the following medical situation:

3 entities:
**Consultation**, with one nullable **Prescription**.
Prescription with a set of **Medicine**s.

I've modelled them as follows: (Java code stripped of unnecessary info)

```
Consultation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "consultation")
    @JoinColumn(name = "prescription_id")
    private Prescription prescription;
}

Prescription {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "consultation_id")
    private Consultation consultation;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "prescription")
    private Set<Medicine> medicines;
}


Medicine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "prescription_id")
    private Prescription prescription;
}
```

The problem:

When I call entityManager.persist(consultation), all the child entities are saved in cascade: prescription and the set of medicines, in their respective tables. The problem is that all the foreign keys values are null.

1. consultation.prescription_id = null
2. prescription.consultation_id = null
3. medicine.prescription_id = null

Hibernate HQL logs:

```
insert into PRESCRIPTIONS (consultation_id, prescription_type) values (?, ?)
insert into MEDICINES (description, name, prescription_id) values (?, ?, ?)
insert into CONSULTATIONS (cost, date_occured, description, diagnosis, employee_id, patient_id, reference_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

What did I misunderstand in the cascading mechanism?

Comment: Why do you have a `@JoinColumn` on **both** sides of the `@OneToOne`? You are running the risk that they could become out of sink. In `Consultation` it's probably best to have just the `mappedBy` without a join column.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you did not update the owner sides of the associations; Hibernate does not check inverse sides when flushing the associations to the database.

Make sure to properly update `consultation` field in `Prescription`, and `prescription` field in `Medicine`.

Cascading has nothing to do with the ownership of associations; it just determines which entity lifecycle operation is cascaded to the associated entities.